# Doing an awk command for a conditional statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm doing a bash script using the Awk command to format a file with some user info, and at the beginning of the script, I want it to say "if the value in column 1 is not in the format abc123, skip that line. It doesn't seem to be working though.

I had this previously:

```
$1=="UID" || $1=="rslavin" {
  next
}
```

but of course that wouldn't work for other input files with different usernames.

So, this is what I've tried most recently:

```
$1!=([a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}) {

 next

}
```

The input file looks like:

```
1 UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
2 adz110 5344 5334 0 08:47 pts /2 00:00:00 bash
3 dmq292 6908 6854 0 Jun04 pts /1 00:00:00 bash
4 adz110 7227 7150 0 Jul11 pts /9 00:00:00 who
5 erg474 7466 7461 0 08:54 pts /10 00:00:00 ls
6 dmq292 7966 7960 0 Jun04 pts /13 00:00:00 assign1 . sh if of
7 xle135 8983 8636 0 08:59 pts /15 00:00:00 ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
8 zeh458 9057 1980 0 08:59 pts /7 00:00:00 vim prog . c
9 rslavin 9150 9139 0 08:59 pts /16 00:00:00 ps - af
10 xle135 8636 8628 0 08:58 pts /15 00:00:00 bash
```

Comment: ha nvmnd I found the solution after all. I should've been using !~ instead of !=. So it's: $1 !~ /[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}/ { next }

Comment: The operators `==` and `!=` represent equal to and not-equal too. These operators do not do a regular expression comparison, but a string or numeric comparison. If you want to check against a regular expression you have to use the operators `~` and `!~`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown Input_file the column which we are talking about is `$2` NOT `$1`, so ideally it should be:

```
awk '$2 !~ /[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}/{next}.........' Input_file
```

Also in case you want to check small and capital both letters then try:

```
awk '$2 !~ /[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/{next}..........'  Input_file
```